# Skin Rotation in Lunar client

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Every time I go into Lunar client my skin's head is rotated 120 degrees. I do not understand that. Even with all the other skins I own.

Comment: I dont know why it happenes all the time.

Comment: I don't think your answer can relate to all 4 of these tags. This doesn't appear to be related to commands or legacy console edition.  Please only use related tags when asking a question. Welcome to Arqade!